# animate from list to detail with background in header

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have been trying for some time now to create it myself or find a good example of how to do this in the best way possible. I want to recreate this basically : http://www.materialup.com/posts/plaid

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or example of how to do this, im neon-page-animating from a list to a page that looks like i want it, but making that smooth transition is not something i have been successfull at yet. Please help.

Comment: Two good places to start are [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMhq1o0DULM) video on `neon-animated-pages` and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwvi1u4XXzc) video on `neon-animation`.

Comment: Thank you, but i was more specifically looking for how to accomplish the list -> detail, where the detail page consists of a paper-scroll-header-panel with the image as the background-image. Any idea of what im getting at and where to find a working example of this?

Comment: Have you watched any of the videos? In one of the videos there is a demo of one element 'morphing' into another. That sounds like exactly what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Like Ben Thomas said, you should use the [neon-animated-pages](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation) component for that.

You can also take a look at these official demos that are somewhat similar to what you want to achieve :

[grid demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid/index.html) - [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/tree/master/demo/grid)

[tiles demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/tiles/index.html) - [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/tree/master/demo/tiles)

Comment: Thank you, but i was more specifically looking for how to accomplish the list -> detail, where the detail page consists of a paper-scroll-header-panel with the image as the background-image. Any idea of what im getting at and where to find a working example of this?